# How can I solve lag issue while changing weapon?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've been dealing with this problem for 2-3 days. It doesnt affect gameplay or performance. It is just usual and I believe it is related to console commands.

related video

btw here I got around 60 fps (I guess bcz of the fraps) but it is same @ 130-140 fps. This is how it should look like @0:09

And this is my current config which I took via host_writeconfig 
http://pastebin.com/5YPaqtJY

Comment: Why do you think it is console command related?

Comment: @ColinD I changed some commands a while ago. I dont know what was wrong before but it is now quite good for my gameplay. That is why I dont want to reinstall or verify game cache.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about, even from the video. It takes time to switch weapons- that's all you're seeing as far as I can tell.

Comment: @decency it is llike it switches twice in a move. And when you use awp and quick switching it delays alot

Comment: are you using a mouse wheel to switch? or pressing 1,2,3,etc...

Comment: it does not matter, different keys or weapon choosing keys

Answer (score 1):

Can you describe the lag you're talking about?

Most of the HP(High-Power) weapons have a delay before using them because they are high damage.

I.E. AWP (Magnum Sniper Rifle) takes about 0.7 seconds before the first shot can be taken and has a reload time of 0.9-1.4 seconds between shots.

**OR**

are you having issues between scrolling the mouse wheel and the weapons are not fast-switching?

Follow these steps (working on knowledge from CS:S):

1. Click Options from top of screen (Know that part for sure)
2. Click Keyboard
3. Click Advanced...
4. Check Enable Fast Weapon Switch
5. Click apply or OK.

Comment: It doesnt occur only while fast switching. It also happens when you just change weapon to smth. going to upload a video soon

Comment: That is competitive slowdown, as I refer to it. Although when you do get a video please post a link in a comment so i can edit my answer to assist you further.

Comment: I did upload now